# How to transfer data from a list to another list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a mission system which randomly pick 5 element from a list that store all the missions. But it seems I can't transfer the object from one list to another. Here is what I got so far.

```
void Awake()
{
    Object[] getScriptableObject = Resources.LoadAll("Scriptable Objects/Missions/sideMission");
    temp = new List<ScriptableObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < getScriptableObject.Length; i++)
    {
        temp.Add((ScriptableObject)getScriptableObject[i]);
    }

    if (missionContainer.mission.Count < 5)
    {
        missionContainer.mission.Add(temp[Random.Range(0, temp.Count)]);
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

the temp List search every mission scriptable object in the folder and store them in the temp list, and I want the mission List to randomly pick 5 from the temp list and store them. What should I do?

```
 public class missionContainer : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<ScriptableObject> mission = new List<ScriptableObject>();
}
```

This is the mission list.

Comment: The `temp` list seems completely unnecessary .. why not simply pick a random entry directly from the `getScriptableObject` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you could use the generic typed version

```
// Or even better use the actual type of your ScriptableObject ;)
ScriptableObject[] getScriptableObject = Resources.LoadAll<ScriptableObject>("Scriptable Objects/Missions/sideMission");
```

and then simply do

```
temp = new List<ScriptableObject>(getScriptableObject);
```

And then it sounds like you rather wanted to either allow duplicate entries and use e.g.

```
// Note though that you could also simply directly use
// "getScriptableObject" array instead of "temp" in this case
while (missionContainer.mission.Count < 5)
{
    missionContainer.mission.Add(temp[Random.Range(0, temp.Count)]);
}
```

or if you need unique entries do something like e.g.

```
while (missionContainer.mission.Count < 5)
{
    if(temp.Count == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Didn't find enough resources!", this);
        break;
    }

    var random = Random.Range(0, temp.Count);
    var item = temp[random];
    missionContainer.mission.Add(item);
    temp.Remove(item);
}
```

In case the `missionContainer` is actually also a `ScriptableObject` you might want to first call

```
missionContainer.mission.Clear();
```

in order to start with an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

That would never add more than one mission. Don't you mean:

```cs
while (missionContainer.mission.Count < 5)
{
    missionContainer.mission.Add(temp[Random.Range(0, temp.Count)]);
}
```

But you are not removing the mission from the temp list, so you might add it again.

Comment: thx for pointing out that. but right now i cant even get a single mission to transfer, anything else i did wrong ？

Comment: Only two things can make it not add a mission: You don't call Awake or you already have 5 missions (or more) in the missionContainer.